# About actions admin file Django?

Tags: django, action, admin

How to send param not  POST but from  GET  to action do_send

```
class BlogAdminCategory(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def do_send(self, request, queryset):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/json")
        serializers.serialize("json", queryset, stream=response)
        return response
    do_send.short_description = 'Hide'

    actions = [
        do_send
    ]
    save_on_top= True
    list_display =('title_category','pub_date','hide_me',)

    def hide_me(self, obj):
        # how to send param not  POST but from  GET category to action do_send
        return '<a href="send_do?id={0}">Hide</a>'.format(obj.id)  

    hide_me.short_description = 'Hide'
    hide_me.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When you are performing an action in the admin you are POSTing a form that contains the values of those objects which you selected the action to be performed on. It wouldn't work as a GET

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1240

> Handle an admin action. This is called if a request is POSTed to the
>   changelist; it returns an HttpResponse if the action was handled, and
>   None otherwise.